# Search is not working - Reset Cache config

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, cache

I'm using SharePoint 2013 (only 1 server). When I search something, it does not return anything.

As I googled it, I found that this could come from the cache configuration. So I have to clear the folder (But NOT delete it) by deleting all files except cache.ini where I should put 1. I get that.

In the SharePoint\Config folder, I have to GUID folders. On with cache.ini, and another one with only "persistedfile" (19 files). All of them have "modified time" equal to one particular day (Last summer) and time. Should I delete this folder ? I'm not sure it's in use by SharePoint ...

I will do this in order to solve my search problem: in event viewer, I got 6482 ID error :

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpdatedConcurrencyException.

I guess this is related to my search error result.

SharePoint is standalone with SQL installed. And I must admit that I really don't know what I've been done with the search service, and what's wrong.

EDIT: When I clear the cache folder, shoud I delete the TMP files too (as I delete XML config files) ?

Comment: Delete existing search service application and recreate new search service application then ran full crawl of all content source.

Comment: Thanks for comment @NagarajuPattem. Does this present any risk ? you advice me to do this before creating the cache ?

Comment: Keep old one and create new search service application after that associate this service application as default to one web application.

Comment: Should I use an existing app pool for web service and web admin ? "SharePoint Web Services Default" is a good idea ?

Comment: How can I "associate this service application as default to one web application" ?

Comment: Ok, I find it - CA > App Management, highlight web app > Services connection > Custom

Comment: yes switch default to custom, did that working or not?

Comment: Source content is still building ...